# How to open a website with redirects

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-addon, privacy

I'm trying to visit 99designs.com from Italy and it always redirects me to the .it website, while I want the USA version. I tried to disable **geo.enabled** inside **about:config** page in firefox but this is not helping.

I also used **TunnerlBear** switching to USA servers, it works for a few minutes then the server will not respon (both websites) is there a safe/legal way to open a direct website and not being redirected?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think this is server side. I'm not sure you can work around this with an addon.

Comment: The server is probably redirecting you based on your IP.  You will need to use a VPN (or other such technology) configured such that you appear to be in a different location (e.g. in the USA).

Answer (score 0):

I dropped a line to support and after its and bits they gave me (us) the solution, I tried something similar but didnt knew the correct variable to pass:

> https://99designs.com/?noredirect=true